# seed cloudinary photos for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, seed

)

I have some cloudinary's photos and I would like to make a seed (in my rails app).
I'm using Carrierwave.

In my seed, I try to put the cloudinary's url image :

```
Course.create! ({
  photo: "fismpnq3zma80dc2ovjt.jpg"
)}
```

But it's don't work. What can I do ?

If I ask by console :

```
pry(main)> c = Course.first
....
pry(main)> c.photo

@cache_id=nil,
@file=nil,
@filename=nil,
....
@model=#<Way:0x00007f80e7a3a9c0
photo:nil,
....
@mounted_as=:photo,
@versions=nil>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `create` method, the parameters need to be verified (by signature) before the SDK will save them.

For example:

```
resource_type = "image" 
type = "upload"
version = 1234567890
public_id = "fismpnq3zma80dc2ovjt"
format = "jpg"
signature = Cloudinary::Utils.api_sign_request({:public_id=>public_id, 
:version=>version}, Cloudinary.config.api_secret)
photo = "#{resource_type}/#{type}/v#{version}/#{public_id}.#{format}## 
{signature}"
Course.create!({ photo: photo )}
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

--Yakir

Comment: Thank you for these explanations. But I've made a lot easier : 

Course.create!({ photo: open("http://res.cloudinary.com/...photo.jpg") )}