# Cannot set photo url of seeds in rails app using cloudinary gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary, seed

I coded a job platform with rails and when you add a new job, you can upload a photo (the logo of the company). I used cloudinary and everything is working fine.

But now I coded a scraper in my seed file.
It scrapes a job site for jobs.

But when I set:
Job.create(title: job_title, description: job_description, photo: "image/upload/qwxcsitnlxzbjvannpbm")

the job is created but the photo ist nil.

I now found that it does not work this way as with cloudinary the parameters need to be verified.

I found this thread that explains the problem:
[seed cloudinary photos for rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163036/seed-cloudinary-photos-for-rails-app)

But when I follow the first solution, the job (or vacancy as I call it) is still nil:

```
resource_type = "image"
  type = "upload"
  version = 1234567890
  public_id = "wv7l1o6xwimtfvx2oxdw"
  format = "jpg"
  signature = Cloudinary::Utils.api_sign_request({:public_id=>public_id,
  :version=>version}, Cloudinary.config.api_secret)
  photo = "#{resource_type}/#{type}/v#{version}/#{public_id}.#{format}## .
  {signature}"
  Vacancy.create(title: job_title, companyname: 'Lillydoo', jobdescription: job_description, photo: photo)
```

when I follow the second solution, I get the error "TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String"

here is the second code:

```
Vacancy.create!({ photo: open("https://res.cloudinary.com/dfom3nog0/image/upload/v1543327271/qwxcsitnlxzbjvannpbm.png") })
```

Hope someone can help me find an easy way to solve this! Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you check the validations on `Vacancy` model?

`create!` usually raises error if the validations fail

Comment: There's a typo in the in one line I believe. It should be: `photo = "#{resource_type}/#{type}/v#{version}/#{public_id}.#{format}##{signature}"`. Let me know if that works?

Comment: This was it -  Thanks so much for the quick help!